# Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/file.csv' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2) (Android API version: 33)

Tags: flutter, android-external-storage

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />

android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

and run time permissions:

```
                                  await [
                                    p.Permission.storage,
                                  ].request();
                                  await [
                                    p.Permission.accessMediaLocation,
                                  ].request();
                                  await [
                                    p.Permission.manageExternalStorage,
                                  ].request();
```

but still i got error in android 13 .

```
Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/file.csv' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

and code is this:

```
var directory = Platform.isAndroid
    ? await getExternalStorageDirectory() //FOR ANDROID
    : await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String newPath = "";
List<String> paths = directory.path.split("/");
for (int x = 1; x < paths.length; x++) {
  String folder = paths[x];
  if (folder != "Android") {
    newPath += "/" + folder;
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
//newPath = newPath + "/SENSEnutsReport";
directory = Directory(newPath + "/Download");
if (!await directory.exists()) {
  directory = await Directory(newPath + "/Download").create();
}    if (await directory.exists()) {
      File f = new File(directory.path + "/${fileData.csv}");
      if (f.existsSync()) {
      } else {
        f = await File(directory.path + "/${fileData.csv}")
            .create(recursive: true);
      }
      final input = f.openRead();
   }
```

This code in word on android 12 but does't work on android 13.
ThankYou if anyone can help.

Comment: It's telling you that the file or directory doesn't exist, so pretty sure it has nothing to do with permissions.